# What are the two classes of time formatting characters called?

Tags: php, python, date-formatting, difference

Some environments (such as PHP) designate the HH:MM:SS time format with `H:i:s`, and others (such as Python and date) use `%H:%M:%S`. **What are these two classes of time formatting characters called**, and from where do they originate? Notice that in addition to the use or lack of percent signs, in the former style the minutes are represented with `i` whereas in the latter minutes are represented with `M`. Likewise seconds and other units may be represented differently.

I ask as I deal with multiple environments and knowing the proper terminology will help me remember which style to use in which environment, and will additionally help me to search the fine web when encountering issues.

Comment: Python follows the [C `sprintf` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) here.

Comment: Do any environments *other* than PHP not have the format specifier flag?

Comment: In the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), they are referred to as "format codes".

Comment: @jonrsharpe: and `sprintf` talks about *format specifiers*.

Comment: It is actually not the terms "format codes" or "format specifiers" that I am interested in, but rather "Foo-style format" vs. "Bar-syle format". It would help me to remember "Javascript uses Bar-style formatting for date strings".

Comment: I've always called them "format specifiers" v.s. "custom syntax that makes L10N a royal pain in the ass".

Comment: @dotancohen: I'd refer to them as C-style and PHP-style. [Django uses PHP-style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date), for example.

Comment: That said, there is no official term or anything. PHP invented their own, by all accounts (anything else using the same format refers to PHP). But there is no canonical source to point to, this is then purely opinion based.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn. I think that you are right, I cannot find anything else that uses the PHP format. I'll keep looking, but it appears that it the correct answer.

Comment: Martin, could you please make your comments into an answer? According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date), only templates use this format, and do so to be compatible with PHP. I'll accept that answer. Thank you!